# Processing an array in php?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

I seem to have run into a problem with my php, getting this error:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string,
>   array given in
>   /home/nightl7/public_html/demos/autocompletejquery/submit.php on line
>   27
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user
>   'nightl7'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/nightl7/public_html/demos/autocompletejquery/submit.php on line
>   36
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server
>   could not be established in
>   /home/nightl7/public_html/demos/autocompletejquery/submit.php on line
>   36 Access denied for user 'nightl7'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   SELECT * FROM markers WHERE select3 = ''

This is the code I have:

```
<?php
require("db_access.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

$name=$_POST['name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$type=$_POST['type'];
$request=$_POST['$_REQUEST'];

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$inputs = array('select3');
$where  = array();


foreach($inputs as $input)
{
    if(!empty($_POST[$input])) {
        $where[] = "{$input} = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$input]) . "'";
    }
}

if ($where) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM markers WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
} else {
    user_error("No rows returned by:<br />\n$query"); 
}
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result == false) {
   die(mysql_error() . "<br />\n$query");
}
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   user_error("No rows returned by:<br />\n$query");
} 

// Fetch the result    
$rowset = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $rowset[] = $row;
}

// Look at your rowset structure:
print_r($rowset);


header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

And I don't know why I'm getting a password error since this is what my db_access.php looks like:

```
<?
$username="nightl7_mapus";
$password="MYPASSWORD - is is correct :)";
$database="nightl7_map";
?>
```

Comment: Please fix your title: a list of technologies is not a description of your question. The question which is... um, what, exactly?

Comment: Hello, my question is how I can make that above code work. I read about may different types of arrays and I still can't decide if what I did was right.

Comment: My feeling is that this is _waaaaay_ too broad for SO. Do you have a specific question about a programming language?

Comment: Hello.... now I do :))) I ran into an error, will update question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have so far looks pretty good. You  have properly escaped the SQL inputs when building your `WHERE` clause. You've properly checked for errors in your query result. Looks like the next thing you need to do is fetch your query result rows:

```
// You already have....
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result == false) {
   die(mysql_error() . "<br />\n$query");
}
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   user_error("No rows returned by:<br />\n$query");
} 

// Fetch the result    
$rowset = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $rowset[] = $row;
}

// Look at your rowset structure:
print_r($rowset);

// then do something with the $rowset array
```

**UPDATE** Problems with your `db_access.php`:

If your username and password are correct in this file, perhaps it isn't being parsed correctly because `short_open_tags` are disabled on your web server.

Try changing `<?` to `<?php` in `db_access.php`.

Comment: Hello Michael, do you know why I could be getting a password error when I have included my db access in the php? Thanks :)

Comment: @user944589 See my update. It might be the short PHP open tag `<?`

Comment: The mistake was 'select3 =' :) There is no such column and I forgot about that